# If statement using a character or string in C not working

Tags: c

I'm trying to create something that gets an input from a user which is a y or n and using an if statement to check which one it is.

```c
char shChoice[1];
    printf("Would you like to buy something else?(y/n): ");
    scanf("%s", &shChoice);
    printf("%s", shChoice);
    if (shChoice == "y"){
        interface();
    }else if(shChoice == 'n'){
        finalizer();
    }else{
        printf("Failed");
    }
```

I was expecting it to be able to do it but instead i got failed. it would print the letter (y) when it was entered but it still ends up printing failed.

Comment: The `scanf` format `%s` creates a ***null-terminated** string. For a one-character string it means `scanf` will write *two* characters to the array. Furthermore, you can't compare string using `==`, you need to use the `strcmp` function. It seems you have skipped too much of your beginners books, tutorials or classes, as all this should be covered.

Comment: I see `"y"` (double quote) and `'n'` (single quote), are you aware of that?

Comment: `shChoice` can store strings of a maximum length of 0 (yes, zero).  You probably want something like `char shChoice[100];` or so. Also it's `scanf("%s", shChoice)` and `"n"`  ( not `'n'`). And you cannot comparre strings with `==`. Read the chapter dealing with strings in youc C text book. For comparing strings you need `strcmp`.

Comment: A C string is only a **null terminated** character array. With 2 consequences: 1/ you need one more position for the terminating null (`char shChoice[2];`) and 2/ equality with `==` will  test pointer equality (an array *decays* to a pointer when used directly) and you need to use the functions from string.h for comparison or any other processing. TL/DR: find a tutorial for C string processing and read it.

Comment: If you only want to read a single character, you can do `char shChoice;` `scanf(" %c", &shChoice); /* note the space before %c is important */` `printf("%c", shChoice);` `if (shChoice == 'y') {` `} else if (shChoice == 'n') {` `}`.

Answer (score 1):

I used strcmp() since apparently i am not able to do it just like that! But everyone was very helpfull!(This went okay i think for my first question! Thanks for all who answered!)

Comment: The problem is that you aren't supposed to use a string here, but a single character. So `%s` is wrong, declaring an array is wrong, using `strcmp` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `%s` you should use  `%c`.

Note that the white space before `%c` is important, because you tell the scanf to ignore any blank spaces, tabs, or newlines in the input before reading the character. This is useful if you want to avoid considering unwanted white spaces in the input.

And when you compare characters in c you should use single quotes and not double quotes. Because double quotes are used for strings.

```
char shChoice;

printf("Would you like to buy something else?(y/n): ");
scanf(" %c", &shChoice);
printf("%c\n", shChoice);
if (shChoice == 'y' || shChoice == 'Y'){
   interface();
}else if(shChoice == 'n' || shChoice == 'N'){
   finalizer();
}else{
   printf("Failed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Point 1:

char shChoice[1] will lead to a memory overflow because scanf() appends '\0' at the end of user's input.

I would allocate more bytes: shChoice[128]

---

Point 2:

Use this: if (shChoice[0] == 'y')

Bye,
Enrico Migliore